# Father-child process use pipe to talk, hangs after "execlp", why?

Tags: linux, process, pipe, fork, freeze

I've got a simple text file called "tmp" under current directory, I wish to "cat" this file and then "sort" it, I want to use a c program to act like pipe "|" so I tried to use a father/child talk to do this.

Unexpectedly, the program hangs after "cat", like below:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
int main(){
    int pipefd[2];
    pipe(pipefd);
    int& readfd=pipefd[0];
    int& writefd=pipefd[1];

    pid_t pid=fork();
    if(pid==0){//child
        dup2(STDIN_FILENO,writefd);
        close(readfd);
        execlp("cat","cat","tmp",NULL);
        printf("child cat ends\n");
        exit(0);
    }else{//father
        dup2(STDOUT_FILENO,readfd);
        close(writefd);
        execlp("sort","sort",NULL);
        printf("father sort ends\n");
    }
    int status;
    wait(&status);
    printf("father exists\n");
    return 0;
}
```

g++ to compile and run this file, after "cat" tihis file, I don't even see "child cat ends", it just hangs.

Where's the problem, how to fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) The order of arguments in dup2 is incorrect. Look at [dup2](https://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2)

2) parameters (stdin/stdout) to dup2 are incorrect.

3) The exec() family of functions replace the process image with a new one.  So the code after that call does not get to run (unless the exec() fails), so I removed those.

Here is the code:

```
 #include <stdlib.h>
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <unistd.h>

 int main(){
   int pipefd[2];
   pipe(pipefd);
   int& readfd = pipefd[0];
   int& writefd = pipefd[1];

   pid_t pid = fork();

   if(pid == 0){ //child
     dup2(writefd, 1);  // 1 is STDOUT_FILENO -- cat already has input -- needs output
     close(readfd);
     execlp("cat","cat","tmp.txt", NULL);
     perror("execlp() failed in child");

   }else{ //father
     dup2(readfd, 0); // 0 is STDIN_FILENO -- because sort needs input!
     close(writefd);
     execlp("sort","sort", NULL);
     perror("execlp() failed in parent");
   }
   return 0;
 }
```